# Python Tkinter Threding

Tags: tkinter, python-multithreading

So i wanted to get into classes in python in general and specifically into tkinter.
I just wanted to create a small project to get the hang of things, but i got stuck when i tried to add *threading* into my program. (probably wasn't smart of me to try and learn a bunch of things at once.. I know..)
The purpose of my program is to have a small 'car' driving around, able to accelerate or slow down and to turn to the sides, while keeping it inside a square, so that i'll be able to see her all of the time.
Here's the code: (quite messy, just didn't know what part is the issue...)

```
from tkinter import *
import turtle as Tr
import threading


class MyApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self,master)
        self.grid()
        self.MakeBob()
        self.createButtons()
        walls_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.PutWalls)
        stay_in = threading.Thread(target=self.StayIn)
        move_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.Move)
        walls_thread.start()
        stay_in.start()
        move_thread.start()

    def PutWalls(self):
        joe = Tr.Turtle()
        joe.ht()
        joe.pu()
        joe.goto(-300,-300)
        joe.pd()
        joe.goto(-300,300)
        joe.goto(300,300)
        joe.goto(300,-300)
        joe.goto(-300,-300)

    def MakeBob(self):
        self.bob = Tr.Turtle()
        self.speed = 0
        self.bob.pu()
        self.bob.seth(90) #Up.


    def createButtons(self):
        #Accelerate:
        self.Accelerate = Button(width=2,bg="green",fg="white",text=chr(1640),command=self.Accelerate)
        self.Accelerate.grid(row=0,column=0)

        #Deccelerate:
        self.Deccelerate = Button(width=2,bg="green",fg="white",text=chr(1639),command=self.Deccelerate)
        self.Deccelerate.grid(row=1,column=0)

        #Right:
        self.TurnRight = Button(width=2,bg="blue",fg="white",text=">",command=self.Right)
        self.TurnRight.bind("w",self.Right)
        self.TurnRight.grid(row=1,column=2)

        #Left:
        self.TurnLeft = Button(width=2,bg="blue",fg="white",text="    <",command=self.Left)
        self.TurnLeft.grid(row=1,column=1)

        #my original thought was that i could use buttons as threading.. ^-^

    def StayIn(self):
        while True:
            if not (-300<self.bob.xcor()<300 and -300<self.bob.ycor()<300):
                self.bob.goto(0,0)
    def Accelerate(self):
        if self.speed < 10:
            self.speed += 0.5

    def Deccelerate(self):
        if self.speed > 0:
            self.speed -= 0.5

    def Right(self):
        self.bob.right(8)

    def Left(self):
        self.bob.left(8)

    def Move(self):
        while True:
            self.bob.forward(self.speed)


    def EXIT(self):
        root.destroy()
root = Tk()
app = MyApp(master=root)
app.master.title("My Do-Nothing Application")
app.master.maxsize(100, 75)
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter isn't thread safe, and for such a simple project you don't need threads.  Do a search on this site for `[tkinter] animation`

Comment: Moreover, concurrent programming isn't so trivial at all. Learn step by step. Learn classes, then tkinter and finally concurrent programming. Playing around with multi-threading isn't enough in my opinion. You need to read and learn well the concepts.